# Zxing - pressing back button from camera view, before reading any qr codes

Tags: android, android-activity, qr-code, zxing

This is part of the code that I've used to implement the QR code scanner,using zxing library.

Once the button is clicked, mScannerView.stopCamera() is activated, and the screen for scanning is shown. If I press phones back button from that screen, before any qrcode is read, the app completely closes and it does not go back to the previous activity. How do I go back to the previous activity(from where the startCamera() was called) when I press the back button on the phone, before reading any qr codes? Any ideas?

New Activity:

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class New extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

```
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
}
public void onClick(View v){
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    //Do anything with result here :D
    Log.w("handleResult",result.getText( ));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    //Resume scanning uncomment below
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using a customized scanner? Have you tried using `IntentIntegrator`? Using this saves a lot of problem. [Here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent)

Comment: @tingyik90
If I'm to use the IntentIntegrator, how could I handle the same scenario? Once integrator.initiateScan()  is called, the camera screen comes up for scanning and only when a QR code is read, the following method is activated:

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)

Then how do I handle the case where I press back button from the scanning screen, before a qr code is read?

Comment: After calling `intentIntegrator.initiateScan()`, you will always return to your original activity, even when back button is pressed. You should call `intentIntegrator.initiateScan()` within your original activity. Are you asking about how to return to your original activity? or asking about how to handle the scanning result (that has no result)?

Comment: I was asking about returning to the previous  activity without reading any qr code.

Comment: Yeah, so have you tried? Pressing back will always call `onActivityResult`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use this package. See https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded. Clear instruction is available for setting it up in Gradle.

In your original activity, add the followings.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // if user scanned and the result is valid, do your stuff here
    } else {
        // if user pressed back or there's error, do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to edit the text "Scan a barcode", which is displayed by default at the bottom of  the scanning screen, of the package you suggested? If you could tell how to edit that text,that'd be appreciated.

Comment: Okay I found it from the description in GitHub. Thanks mate!

Comment: If you feel this is a correct answer, please accept my answer and upvote. Thanks.